# Why does "Hodl Hodl" not seem to... support Bitcoin?

Tags: decentralization, p2p, lending

After listening to this podcast, I got extremely excited for Hodl Hodl: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJe7LIZ6cdI

But then I went to their site and see this: https://lend.hodlhodl.com/offers/lend

*Every single offer* just talks about "Eth" or "DAI" or "Liquid" or "USDT" or "WBTC" or some other cryptic symbol. What?

I thought this was about lending Bitcoin? Not Ether or a bunch of "weirdcoins" which I don't have and don't want.

What am I missing now? It doesn't even let you select "BTC" in the list of currencies, so it's not just currently unavailable, but *entirely* unavailable.

What's said in the podcast and the actual webpage seem to have nothing to do with each other. I'm confused. What am I missing?

UPDATE: I've sat here for an hour and tried to register an account. Even when it eventually stops showing the CAPTCHAs, it just reloads the registration form. This is not a real website. It's just yet another vaporware/scam. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a scam. It doesn't allow lending Bitcoin, you are correct. When it says it supports Bitcoin, it means it allows you to use Bitcoin as collateral for a loan.

For example, if you want to borrow USDT, you'd be allowed to post an appropriate amount of BTC as your collateral, receive USDT, then when you pay back your USDT loan, you receive the BTC you posted as collateral back. If you default on the loan, then the lender receives the BTC you put up as collateral.